# SQL query construction as json object from multiple column

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am try to get result like combine multiple column as single column in result but not got success.
how to get exepected result?

**query:**

```
 select SchemaName,([create],[read],[update],[delete]) as [Permissions] from ApplicationRoles for json path;
```

**Exepected Result:**

```
{
  "SchemaName": "TestSchema",
  "Permissions": {
    "create": true,
    "read": true,
    "update": true,
    "delete": true
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the values you want in an additional array in a subquery:

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.YourTable(SchemaName sysname,
                           [create] bit,
                           [read] bit)
INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable
VALUES ('TestSchema',1,1);
GO
SELECT YT.SchemaName,
       (SELECT YT.[create],
               YT.[read]
        FOR JSON PATH) AS Permissions --No WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER as this will result in "Permissions": "{\"create\":true,\"read\":true}"
FROM dbo.YourTable YT
FOR JSON AUTO, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER;
GO
DROP TABLE dbo.YourTable;
```

Comment: WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER is not working..either using or not getting result  always as array

Comment: What do you mean "not working"? It works fine for me, @r08 . [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=245edc52df366754ec6d4cd9cbf5c819) As I mentioned, including `WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER` in the subquery will result in `"{\"create\":true,\"read\":true}"`, because `"Permissions": {"create":true,"read":true}` is **not** valid JSON. It's also [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/remove-square-brackets-from-json-without-array-wrapper-option?view=sql-server-ver15#example-multiple-row-result) that such syntax is not valid.

Comment: Permissions column return as array instead of json object.

Comment: ... For the 3rd time @r08 `"Permissions": {"create":true,"read":true}` *isn't* valid JSON, @r08 ... It has to be an array.